# Django query after a given character

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to filter data from the postgres database connected to my django app. The data in the database column to be filtered is in this format:

```
Name|ABC & facilities:Unit|XY Unit
```

I want to write a django query that matches the search text after the last pipe ("|") symbol. How can this be done to return the data in shortest time possible.

I tried writing a query

```
Mymodel.objects.filter(name__iendswith=searchTxt)
```

but it's not returning any result.

Comment: `Mymodel.objects.raw("select * from the_table where split_part(the_column, '|', 3) = the_search_text")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have used the above script but it's not returning any value from the database, what could be the issue.